# Pandas: Merge data with different timing

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames that contain time-series data that are on different ranges. One starts earlier, and ends earlier. Also, one is monthly and one is quarterly. However, the index of both is in the form of YYYY-MM-DD. Is there a cute way of merging these dataframes using "Python" and "Pandas"?

Thanks!

/edit
One set:

```
          DATE    GDP  GPDI     NFLS
0   1947-01-01  243.1  35.9  112.815
1   1947-04-01  246.3  34.5  111.253
2   1947-07-01  250.1  34.9  113.023
3   1947-10-01  260.3  43.2  111.440
```

The other one:

```
           DATE   INDPRO  M08354USM310NNBR  GDP
(...)
334  1946-11-01  13.3916               NaN  NaN
335  1946-12-01  13.4721               NaN  NaN
336  1947-01-01  13.6332              42.8  NaN
337  1947-02-01  13.7137              42.5  NaN
```

Together I would like to join them, such that

```
      DATE INDPRO  M08354USM310NNBR  GDP   GPDI     NFLS
1946-11-01 13.3916              NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN  
1946-12-01 13.4712              NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN
1947-01-01 13.6332             42.8  243.1 35.9     112.815           
1947-02-01 13.7137             42.5  NaN    NaN     NaN
(...)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: You just do an outer merge on the left and right hand side indices, are the column names different?

Comment: Provided example. Column names are the same, outer merge sounds promising.

Comment: In the final merged df what do you want the date to represent if one df is monthly and the other quaterly? You can fix up the merged df after by grouping by date and summing the values and then resetting the index

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Both quarterly and monthly date have the same layout. Quarterly data will have YEAR-01-01, YEAR-04-01 (...) and monthly data has YEAR-01-01, YEAR-02-01 (etc). Note that YEAR-01-01 hence is the same format for both quarterly and monthly and should hold both data. Did this help clarifying?

Comment: Ah I understand your comment now I think - the outer merge works, but the data is in the wrong order... dfProd.sort fixed this. Thanks!

Comment: @FooBar If you do an outer merge and where you have duplicate dates in both dfs will result in duplicate rows as you can see in my answer, are you wanting to merge the duplicated rows as you could have many duplicated rows is my question

Comment: You mean me having the same column in both df (besides DATE)? I'm avoiding that by only selecting a subset of columns, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform a merge the fact the periods are different and don't overlap suits you in fact:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='DATE', how='outer')

merged
Out[54]:
         DATE  GDP_x  GPDI     NFLS   INDPRO  M08354USM310NNBR  GDP_y
0  1947-01-01  243.1  35.9  112.815  13.6332              42.8    NaN
1  1947-04-01  246.3  34.5  111.253      NaN               NaN    NaN
2  1947-07-01  250.1  34.9  113.023      NaN               NaN    NaN
3  1947-10-01  260.3  43.2  111.440      NaN               NaN    NaN
4  1946-11-01    NaN   NaN      NaN  13.3916               NaN    NaN
5  1946-12-01    NaN   NaN      NaN  13.4721               NaN    NaN
6  1947-02-01    NaN   NaN      NaN  13.7137              42.5    NaN

[7 rows x 7 columns]
```

You can rename, fill, drop the erroneous 'GDP_y' column

To sort the merged `'DATE'` column just call `sort`:

```
In [57]:

merged.sort(['DATE'])
Out[57]:
         DATE  GDP_x  GPDI     NFLS   INDPRO  M08354USM310NNBR  GDP_y
4  1946-11-01    NaN   NaN      NaN  13.3916               NaN    NaN
5  1946-12-01    NaN   NaN      NaN  13.4721               NaN    NaN
0  1947-01-01  243.1  35.9  112.815  13.6332              42.8    NaN
6  1947-02-01    NaN   NaN      NaN  13.7137              42.5    NaN
1  1947-04-01  246.3  34.5  111.253      NaN               NaN    NaN
2  1947-07-01  250.1  34.9  113.023      NaN               NaN    NaN
3  1947-10-01  260.3  43.2  111.440      NaN               NaN    NaN

[7 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Sorry, the periods overlap - which should be clear from my example. There should be some rows with NaN on one of the variables, and some rows with both variables filled up.

Comment: I tried dfProd = pd.merge(dfQ[['DATE', 'GDP']], dfM[['DATE', 'INDPRO']], on='DATE' ), but this somehow only gave me rows with both variables having values (I also would like to select only a subset of the variables)

Comment: @FooBar the default merge type is inner so the values have to match in both dfs, is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry, the code above is not what I'm doing - no idea how it arrived in my copy paste. I do `pd.merge(dfQ[['DATE', 'GDP']], dfM[['DATE', 'INDPRO']], on='DATE', how='outer')`